# All Values in json response including numeric values need to be in double quotes

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Iam trying to retrieve the data from the table in json format with below query in SQL Server ,

```
Select * from TableA for json path, root( 'table 1')
```

Iam getting json response as ,

```
{  
    "TableA":[  
        {  
            "Id":34562,
            "A Id":2,
            "Name":"ZDR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where Field "ID" & "A Id" are declared as "int"in the database

Now i need those values should also be displayed within double quotes , is there any way that we can handle in SQL server 2016 itself, to make clear all the field values irrespective of datatype should be enclosed in double quotes please do need full !!!

Like above single query iam having set of 12 quires in a stored procedure eventually when i run the stored procedure i will get a json response where all the values should be enclosed within double quotes .

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: Numbers should not be enclosed in double quotes in JSON.

Comment: Iam using microsoft SQL server 2016 and actually my current requirement every field values should be enclosed with double quotes .

Comment: Why do you want to generate non-standard JSON?

Comment: To bring unifomity in structure where all values shld be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "automagic" way to do this. What you can do is in your `SELECT` statements `CAST` your numeric columns to literal (`varchar` or `nvarchar`):

```
Select CAST(Id as nvarchar(10)) AS Id,
       CAST([A Id], nvarchar(10)) AS "A ID", 
       [Name]
       from TableA for json path, root( 'table 1');
```

Hope this helps!